# Error #include'ing <unordered_map>

Tags: c++, stl, g++

I'm attempting to use unordered_map in a C++ program, but every time I get the error: `boost/unordered_map.hpp: No such file or directory`.

When I received this error at first, I was using Mac OS X 10.8.5, and I wondered if my compiler was not up to the latest C++ standard. I have upgraded to Mavericks 10.9.1, and I have updated command line tools.

I also installed Boost libraries. The original unordered_map appears not to be a Boost library implementation, though, and I would prefer to use the standard, if possible.

When attempting compile normally, without Boost, my #include and command line work fine except for the issue with unordered_map:

```
#include <unordered_map>

g++ -g -Wall testGame.cpp ../card2.cpp ../euchreDeck.cpp -I..
```

When attempting to compile with Boost, I tried two separate command lines, neither of which succeded:

```
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>

g++ -g -Wall testGame.cpp ../card2.cpp ../euchreDeck.cpp -I.. -Iboost_1_55_0
g++ -g -Wall testGame.cpp ../card2.cpp ../euchreDeck.cpp -I.. -lboost_1_55_0
```

Is it an issue with the libraries not being linked properly, are my #include statements incorrect, or am I missing something obvious?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `g++ --version`?

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice if whatever tutorial/book you are following told you all the steps you need to setup your environment fully as a beginner?

Comment: Man, it really would... And @Johnsyweb, sorry, I cleared the text, but as I recall it was: `unordered_map: No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 6):

For `boost` it is likely, that the compiler does not find the library, because `boost` is not in the search path.

For `std` you'll have to use `-std=c++11` since `unordered_map` is a C++11 feature.

Comment: Thank you! I tried using the `-std=c++11` flag before installing the new OS, but it didn't recognize it: now it works. Thanks! As for the boost libraries, are my compiler flags correct if I want to include the boost library in the search path, and I just don't have the right filepath, or are the flags simply incorrect?

Comment: It depends where boost is installed. If it's installed to `/usr/include`, then the compiler should find it directly. But if it's in e.g. `/opt/boost/1.55.0` you'll have to add `-I/opt/boost/1.55.0/include` as flag.

Answer (score -1):

Seens like the compiler can not find your include directory. You also need some like this:
`"-IC:\\PATH_TO_INCLUDE_FOLDER\\include"`